# Xamarin - take screenshot in android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on barcode scanner integration which captures the image after barcode is scanned. I am using XZing tool to do it but it doesnt have this functionlity
So what i am trying to do is to take screenshot of the screen after successful scan of barcode. I am following below article (from one of the SO answers)
http://danielhindrikes.se/xamarin/building-a-screenshotmanager-to-capture-the-screen-with-code/

Now the problem is here that it does takes screenshot. But the camera part is coming in total black color (no image). I can see top and bottom frame of my app. I am passing "MainActivity" class in Activity property. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are other solutions to take a "real screenshot" of what the user can see.

Have a look to `MediaProjection` and `CreateScreenCaptureIntent`:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/ScreenCapture/ScreenCapture/ScreenCaptureFragment.cs

And in Android native to screencap:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png");
```

I think they could work for you.

Comment: Instead of saving it locally on the device, how to run the command and get the image byte or stream to send it directly to server without open/read the written file?